# Installing a Boot Animation without using Root Explorer

Tags: boot-animation

I rooted my HTC Inspire, currently running JellyTime. I want to change my boot animation but the process requires me to access a system folder that is not visible using my current file explorer (ES File Explorer). Is there a way I can change my boot animation without using the app "Root Explorer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES can read/write to protected folders, you just have to enable it in your settings. Open the settings menu (press the menu button, then select "Settings") and find the "Root Settings" item, then enable "Root Explorer" (operate with root permission) and "Mount File System" (allow writing to `/system`).

Alternatively, many devices/Android versions should allow you to simply put the bootanimation.zip file into `/data/local` instead of `/system/media`. You won't need a root explorer for this since `/data/local` is world writable. This doesn't work on all ROMs, though.

Screenshots for the ES settings:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's an option I haven't seen, Thanks A Lot!